# simple preg_replace() not working right for me :/

Tags: php, regex

```
$str = "{Controller}/{Action}";
$str = preg_replace("/\//","\\/",$str);
$str = preg_replace("/(\{\w+\})\\/(\{\w+\})/","\\1 slash \\2",$str);
echo $str;
```

So the third line doesn't do anything for me, could anyone say where i was wrong? It works if i put something else instead of \/
thanks in advance;)

Comment: You need to use `\\\/` in line three, not `\\/`. The reason is because in `\\/`, `\\ ` means a single backslash, while `/` is ending your regular expression. In `\\\/`, `\\` means a backslash, and `\/` means a forward slash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work:

```
$str = "{Controller}/{Action}";
$str = preg_replace('#(\{\w+\})/(\{\w+\})#', '\1 slash \2', $str);

echo $str;
```

Output: `{Controller} slash {Action}`

Remarks:

- You should use single quotes to reduce the need for escaping and therefore much better readability.
- You also should consider using another delimiter if you are matching literal slashes (eg #, but anything works)